# How to make a sentence break at the right place in a parbox within algorithmicx-package?

Tags: algorithmicx, parbox

I have this code

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
{\bf Algorithm:} 
\begin{algorithmic}
\For{$k$ = 1 to $K$}
\For{$n$ = 1 to $N$}
\For{$j$ = 1 to $J$}
\State State.
\State \parbox[t]{20em}{Calculate $\{ {{\boldsymbol{y}} _m} \in {\mathbb{R}^{{J_1} \times {J_2} \times \cdots \times {J_N}}}, \hspace{2em} m = 1,2, \ldots ,M\} $ and ${\psi _{n,j}}$.}
\EndFor
\EndFor
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I would want the sentence break at the digit 1 or 2, not at the equal sign, so that the sentence above the red line can fill this line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `varwidth` rather than `\parbox`, so the box will use the real size. The width given as argument is the maximum width.

Adding `\linebreak[0]` after the comma does the trick; be sure to do this only when the document is in final form, no more changes to the text.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\textbf{Algorithm:}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \For{$k = 1$ to $K$}
    \For{$n = 1$ to $N$}
      \For{$j = 1$ to $J$}
        \State State.
        \State \begin{varwidth}[t]{20em}\raggedright
               Calculate $\{\boldsymbol{y}_m \in 
               \mathbb{R}^{J_1 \times J_2 \times \cdots \times J_N},
               m=1,2,\linebreak[0]\dots,M\}$ and $\psi_{n,j}$.
               \end{varwidth}
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\State Something follows
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I removed all the useless braces and typed in more correctly `$k=1$ to $K$` and similarly in the other parts.

[image]

In order my eyes don't bleed too much, I show the output when

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

is added and `amssymb,amsfonts` removed.

[image]

Magically, the formula fits in the width, but the main aspect is that the math symbols are compatible with the text font.